# Regular expression is too large

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm having issue with this function,

```php
function _where($arg, $separator = ' '){
    if ($arg['where']){
        $operators = '( |=|!=|<>|<|<=|>|>=|=~|!~|\?|\?!)';

        foreach ($arg['where'] as $k => $v){
            if (preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/i', $v, $match)){
                foreach (explode('|', $match[1]) as $or){
                    $where[] = preg_replace('/(.*)'.$operators.'(.*)/i', '\\1\\2\'\\3\'', preg_replace('/\['.str_replace('|', '\|', $match[1]).'\]/i', $or, $v));
                }

                $result[] = '('.join(' or ', $where).')'."\r\n";
            } elseif ($v != 'and' and $v != 'or' and $v != 'xor'){
                $result[] = preg_replace('/(.*)'.$operators.'(.*)/i', '\\1\\2\'\\3\'', $v)."\r\n";
            } else {
                $result[] = $v."\r\n";
            }
        }

        return 'where '.str_replace(array('!~', '=~'), array('not like', 'like'), join($separator, $result));
    }
}
```

And is resulting in,

```
PHP Warning:  preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 63088
```

I am running another site with same code, and issue doesn't exist there, is this issue related to the number of row in db?

Comment: No, the issue is because of PHP version. You're probably running older PHP version, when you get that error.

Comment: Bottom line: You're implementing your query builder in wrong way. Look at Zend Framework 2/Db how they implement `where()` clause

Comment: If it was a DB issue, then you'd get a DB error, not a PHP error. PHP couldn't care less what the DB's capable of. It just sends the query and sees what happens. If the query fails, PHP doesn't care.

Comment: `/\[(.*)\]/i` should most probably be written as `/\[(.*?)\]/i`. As it's written now, it consumes all the text between the first bracket and the very last one, hence an error. And instead of `str_replace` to escape `|` you should use `preg_quote`.

Comment: Can you give the original string and the expected result for this function.

Comment: Thank you all, The issue was with how PHP queried MySQL, I had to re-write some SQL queries and issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue was with how PHP queried MySQL, I had to re-write some SQL queries and issue has been resolved now.

by the OP [D_Guy13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464723/d-guy13) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384914/regular-expression-is-too-large#comment39637604_25384914)